# Compare TCP / network settings between Windows instances

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

I would like to compare the current TCP and/or network settings between two of my Windows Server 2008 instances in order to help me debug a latency issue I am facing. What is the best way to do this? Are there registry keys I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netsh dump` ought to do everything that you need.

/edit - except for any driver settings, which will be specific to the driver(s) in question, so without more info, we can't answer that.